# Tensorflow 2.0 Create a Dataset to feed a model with multiple inputs of different shapes on lazy evaluation

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lazy-evaluation

I have a keras model with two inputs of different shape. One side takes in few categorical features, while the other takes multiple time series with length `PAST_HISTORY`. The output is also multiple time series:

```py
# Categorical data input
input_ct = keras.Input(shape=(len(categ_cols),),
                       name='categorical_input')

# Timeseries input
input_ts = keras.Input(shape=(PAST_HISTORY, len(series_cols)),
                       name='timeseries_input')

...

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_ct, input_ts], outputs=outputs)
```

I created a Dataset for each input and for the output using a pandas DataFrame and some `tf.data.Dataset` operations.

```py
df_ts = df[series_cols][:-FUTURE_TARGET]
ts_batch = lambda window: window.batch(PAST_HISTORY)
time_series_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_ts)\
    .window(PAST_HISTORY, 1, 1, True)\
    .flat_map(ts_batch)

df_cat = df[categ_cols][PAST_HISTORY - 1:-FUTURE_TARGET]
date_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_cat)

df_target = df[target_cols][PAST_HISTORY:]
target_batch = lambda window: window.batch(FUTURE_TARGET)
target_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_target)\
    .window(FUTURE_TARGET, 1, 1, True)\
    .flat_map(target_batch)
```

To create the final Dataset I used a generator:

```py
def generator():
    for d1, d2, t in zip(date_data, time_series_data, target_data):
        yield {"categorical_input": d1, "timeseries_input": d2}, tf.transpose(t)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator,
    output_types=(
        {'categorical_input': tf.int64, 'timeseries_input': tf.float64},
        tf.float64),
    output_shapes=(
        {'categorical_input': (len(categ_cols),),'timeseries_input': (PAST_HISTORY, len(series_cols))},
        (len(target_cols), FUTURE_TARGET),))
```

This worked and I managed to train a model on eager execution by calling `model.fit`. However now that I'm trying to create an `Estimator` from this model the creation of the Dataset no longer works as it implicitly uses the `__iterator__` function which is disallowed on lazy evaluation. Specifically the problem lies in the `zip` operation on the generator.

I tried to create the same dataset without the generator with the following code:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(
        ({'categorical_input': date_data, 'timeseries_input': time_series_data}, target_data)
)
```

This gets me following error when I try to call `estimator.train`:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._NestedVariant'> to Tensor.
Contents: <tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._NestedVariant object at 0x7f5bf84a97f0>.
Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

What is the way to solve this error? Or is there another way to construct this Dataset without having to call an iterator on a Dataset?

Also, I tried to cast the Datasets and got the following error on the windowed Datasets:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.FlatMapDataset'> to Tensor.
Contents: <FlatMapDataset shapes: (None, 2), types: tf.float64>.
Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Dummy data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'ts_1': np.random.rand(10000),
        'ts_2': np.random.rand(10000),
        'ts_objective': np.random.rand(10000),
        'cat_1': np.random.randint(1, 10 + 1, 10000),
        'cat_2': np.random.randint(1, 25 + 1, 10000),
        'cat_3': np.random.randint(1, 30 + 1, 10000),
        'cat_4': np.random.randint(1, 50 + 1, 10000)})

categ_cols = ['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4']
series_cols = ['ts_1', 'ts_2']
target_cols = ['ts_objective']

PAST_HISTORY = 24
FUTURE_TARGET = 8
```

Comment: could you provide your code on google colab for me to debug? I have a few ideas on how to solve but will have to test it first.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt sorry, the data I'm using is confidential so I can't provide a google colab link

Comment: I understand that, but even dummy data using `np.random`. Just to get the idea of what exactly you are dealing with. Because with just those amount of code, everyone can just guess what might be a solution but hardly someone can say it for certain. So that is the reason I am asking to share something so that we can debug your solution. I hope I made sense to you. Thanks

Comment: At least provide a small example of the input so that we can run and debug the code. Otherwise it is very hard to search for an error just by inspecting the code.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt You're right, I provided some dummy data at the end of the description. Thanks

Comment: @HeladioAmaya have you tried out the solution provided, I think using `zip` API will be a good idea. What kind of errors do you get when you use the below solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the dataset you need without using a generator (and much faster) using [`Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) operations only:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

date_data = ...
time_series_data = ...
target_data = ...

def data_tx(d1, d2, t):
    return {"categorical_input": d1, "timeseries_input": d2}, tf.transpose(t)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((date_data, time_series_data, target_data)).map(data_tx)
```

Comment: Worked out great! Just had to remove the `tf.transpose` operation which I found weird since it required it when using the generator but apparently by doing it this way it isn't necessary. Thanks so much!